# Rails concatの挙動について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails 5 アプリケーションプログラムの中の記述でわからない箇所があります。

```
def list_tag(collection, prop)
  content_tag(:ul) do
    collection.each do |element|
      concat content_tag(:li, element.attributes[prop])
    end
  end
end
```

という記述があります。
ビューヘルパー、コレクションにはオブジェクトの配列、プロップにはオブジェクトのプロパティ名。
各オブジェクトの同一プロパティをリスト形式で出力するビューヘルパーです。

ここで疑問なのが、each内でconcatを使用しli要素を出力しているのはわかるのですが、なぜul要素にはconcatが必要ないのでしょうか。ご教授ください。
（初学者なので、ご考慮していただけるとたすかります。Railsのバージョンが古い部分については承知しています）

Answer (score 0):

このメソッドは以下の呼び出し構成になっていると思います。

```
list_tag -> content_tag -> content_tagの引数のブロック
```

`list_tag` は文字列を返す必要があります。 `list_tag` 中で文字列を返すメソッド呼び出しは `content_tag` 一つだけです。なので、`concat` は必要ありません。

逆に、`content_tag`の引数のブロックは、ループにより複数回数のメソッド呼び出しがあるため、ループ毎の結果の文字列を結合する必要があります。このため、`concat` で文字列を結合する必要があります。

`concat` はインスタンス変数の内部バッファ(`output_buffer`)に文字列を結合します。
`content_tag` は引数ブロックで変更された `output_buffer` を結合した状態で、自身の返り値にします。